# Do we always have to use "LIATE" to do integration by parts?

Tags: integration

> Do we always have to use "LIATE" to do integration by parts?
>
> L = logarithms 
> I = inverse trigonometric functions 
> A = algebraic functions 
> T = trigonometric functions 
> E = exponential functions

So basically, an example is a problem like
$$\int -(e^x)\sin x\,dx$$

If I use the LIATE order to integrate this, I will get:

$$- \int (e^x)\sin x \,dx =  e^x \sin x - e^x \cos x - \int e^x\sin x  \,dx$$

If I add $\int e^x\sin x\,dx$ to both sides, I will be left with $0$  on the left-hand side.

But however, if I reverse the order —meaning, I integrate the trigonometric function $\sin x$ and differentiate the exponential part $e^x$ instead of doing the opposite— I can get an answer.

My question is:

> My book said order was a rule. Is it really?

Comment: Because college calculus courses have unfortunately reduced down to just memorization without any conceptual understanding. So as a result of that the entire calculus course is just a list of memorization steps for students to follow. There is nothing wrong with doing integration by parts in any other order, but that is just how the courses are taught since this way of doing it often results in the correct procedure for most routine calculations.

Comment: Some people use "rule" to mean "guideline".  I've always viewed LIATE as a guideline for your first attempt.  Honestly, I had never heard of it until I started teaching...

Comment: Please please use mathjax instead of writing "integralof". You just need to write `$\int f(x) \, dx$` to get $\int f(x) \, dx$.

Comment: In my first calculus book LIPET (log, inverse trig, polynomial, exponential, trig) was the suggested order to take $u$ in $\int u\,dv = uv - \int v\,du$, and it occupied a portion of the margin in the chapter on integration by parts. I think of it as a potentially helpful distillation of the experience gained by lots of trial and tribulation on the part of others, rather than a hard and fast rule.

Comment: I've read that there are counterexamples, but I don't remember the details.

Comment: Someday math education will enter the 21st century and all the above considerations will be moot.  See here:  https://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers

Comment: Messrs Bourbaki, you might be hitting the nail on the head.

Comment: I would say, this is not even required. I learned calculus myself in the lockdown (still in high school), but never heard of this "rule". Integration by parts is more based on intuition and when you do really complicated integrals, then these "rules" don't work most of the time. Believe in your experience, not such rules. Integration involves a lot of hit and trial. These rules only work on low levels, but after that, they don't.

Answer (score 7):

It’s just a rule of thumb designed to make the integration by parts yield something that’s easy to integrate.  It’s based on another rule of thumb, namely that $u$ should be easily differentiable and $dv/dx$ should be easily integrable.  But choosing not to use these rules of thumb won’t get you something mathematically invalid; if violating them allows you to get the answer more efficiently then by all means do so.